# mapStateToProps get url param?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using create-app-react with redux and react-router-dom with 5.2.0 version.

**In App.js**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="container">
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
          <Route path="/about" component={AboutPage} />
          <Route path="/courses" component={CoursesPage} />
          <Route path="/course" component={ManageCoursePage} />
          <Route path="/course/:slug" component={ManageCoursePage} />
          <Route component={PageNotFound} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
```

**In coursePage.js**

```
.......
.......
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  const slug = ownProps.match.params.slug
........
}
.......
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ManageCoursePage)
```

.......

the course slug in the URL with

```
const slug = ownProps.match.params.slug;
```

However, I am finding that "params" is an empty object. To work around this I did the following, which works

```
const slug = ownProps.location.pathname.split('/').reverse()[0];
```

I do not understand how "ownProps.match" does not have the url information when "ownProps.location"

Screenshot for what i did breakpoints it as below:
[image]

Could you please help to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route `<Route path="/courses" component={CoursesPage} />` don't have any params. You can for example rewrite this as `<Route path="/courses/:courseId" component={CoursesPage} />`. After you can access `ownProps.match.params.courseId` in your `CoursesPage` component.

Comment: I have already route with params id 
`<Route path="/course/:slug" component={ManageCoursePage} />` but still same issue!

Comment: You have 2 route suitable for screenshot: `path="/course"` and `path="/course/:slug"`. React router take first. So you need remove `<Route path="/course" component={ManageCoursePage} />`

Comment: I remove `<Route path="/course" component={ManageCoursePage} />` and it goes fine but I need both `path="course"` and `path="/course/:slug"` because it is different page path

Comment: Ok, then move `path="/course"` below `path="/course/:slug"`. And add `exact` to `<Route path="/course/:slug" exact component={ManageCoursePage} />`